# how to allow xss in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website that should be vulnerable to cross-site scripting.

So far I have tried using `innerHTML` but with no luck.

This is the table I want to feature a xss vulnerability

```
    <div id="table">
        <table>
        <thead>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>content</th>
            <th>time</th>
        </thead>
            <tbody id="comments">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And this is the function I want to render the fetched data as scripts if they are formatted as one

```
const comments = document.querySelector("#comments");
fetch("http://localhost:1234/api/comments")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(json => {
        html = "<tr>";
        for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            let comment = json[i];
            html += "<td>" + comment.username + "</td><td>" + 
comment.content + "<td><td>" + comment.created + "</td></tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
        comments.innerHTML = html;
    })
```

If the content of the comment were `<script> alert("danger!") </script>`, I want the content to be rendered as a script with a alert function. And if not, insert it as a regular table element

Comment: "[...] but with no luck." - what exactly happens, why doesn't it work? Is there an error in the console? Is the text content being auto-magically escaped by a higher power?

Comment: innerHTML can't run script tags, thank goodness. use jQuery's `.html(contents)` instead of `.innerHTML=contents`; it will run scripts for you, how handy. XSS like that is usually when the _server_ prints such contents into the "hard-coded" HTML source, the only dynamic way is (afaik) is to document.write() the mal contents, but with an async ajax call, that's not really an option for you.